# Uniform convergence and inequality with derivative of limit

Tags: calculus, limits, uniform-convergence

Let $f_k, f \in C([0,1]; \mathbb{R})$ s.t. $f_k \to f$ uniformly as $k \to + \infty$. Suppose $t \in (0,1)$ and that $f$ is differentiable at $t$. Take $\tau_k$, a sequence of real numbers s.t. $\tau_k \to 0$ and s.t. $0\le t+\tau_k \le 1$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can we prove that

$$ \liminf_k \frac{f_k(t+\tau_k)-f_k(t)}{\tau_k} \ge f'(t) $$
?

Comment: Short answer: no. Try to find a suitable sequence with $f(x) = x$.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try to find it. Do you know any property we can ask to the $f_k$s in order to make the statement true?

Comment: Nothing useful comes to mind. Perhaps this is an XY-problem, and what you really need is something else?